# Displaying MySQL Query Results in a Table (Custom Wordpress Table)?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have created a Wordpress plugin for my employer's site and am testing it on a local server Wordpress installation while developing it.

I know that the plugin has created a MySQL custom table in the Wordpress database and populated it with records. But I want to show the records of the custom table on the admin panel in the backend of the Wordpress site.

This is the code I am using to display the results:

```html
function vac_toplevel_page() {
echo "<h2>" . __( 'Vacancies Info', 'menu-test' ) . "</h2>";
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT property FROM wp_voids";
$rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql );
echo $rows; 
}
```

This only returns the text "Array" on the intended page. I have tried tweaking the code but it either results in the same or no text at all.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't echo an array:

```
// Prepare our Array for viewing:
echo '<pre>';
    // Print the Array
    print_r($rows); 
// Close our prepare Statement
echo '</pre>';
```

This is going to show you the raw data out of the Database, if you want it to look nicer you will need to loop over the array and format it inside your loop.

Database queries typically return multiple rows (in an array) which is why you need to print_r it to see it instead of just echoing it out. Echo only works for single values, see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php 
compared to here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: You're missing a forward slash in your closing `</pre>` tag

Answer (score 0):

echoing a variable having an array dispaly its type . if you want to print content of this array either use print_r($row) or var_dump($row).